# How to send an HTTP request to a PHP page and get the echo'd response in AS3?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

what I want to do is send an HTTP request to a PHP page, get what is being echo'd and return it.

So something like this

PHP Page:

```
<?php
echo "test";
```

The AS3 Code:

```
function openRequest(url) {
      open_page (url);
      return response_from_page;
}
```

So I can use the function in something like this in AS3

```
if (openRequest(php_page.php) == "test") {
   //do
}
```

How can I do this?

I hope I managed to explain the concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlfow.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DVK Ah, I see, sorry, I'll keep that in mind for future references.

Comment: @DVK Should I make another question or what though?

Comment: edit this one if you can

Comment: @KevinL I edited the intro and the title a bit, better?

Comment: @user881239 To do that, you can use a [URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) object like in this [page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cfd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf5) for example ...

Answer (score 0):

As akmozo said in a comment you can use [`URLLoader`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to perform the HTTP request and read the response after the `COMPLETE` event.

However, you can't do this exactly the way you say. ActionScript cannot wait for an asynchronous action (like an HTTP request) before continuing execution, so a function cannot wait before returning a value. In other words `openRequest` *can* open the HTTP request, but it *cannot* wait for the response before returning and exiting the function.

Instead, you can use callbacks to sequence your code:

```
function openRequest(url:String, then:Function):void {
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
    urlLoader.loader(new URLRequest(url));
    function complete(e:Event):void {
        urlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete); // cleanup
        then(urlLoader.data);
    }
}
```

Now you can write your code like this:

```
openRequest("php_page.php", function(response) {
    if (response === "test") {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Note that any code after `openRequest` will get executed immediately, *not* after the response is received. Anything you want to happen *after* the response is received must be placed inside the callback.